# flutter and android studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio

INFO | Android emulator version 32.1.13.0 (build_id 10086546) (CL:N/A) INFO | Found systemPath C:\Users\parma\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-34\google_apis\x86_64\ ERROR | Running multiple emulators with the same AVD ERROR | is an experimental feature. ERROR | Please use -read-only flag to enable this feature. INFO | Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\parma\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash.db, detection is enabled INFO | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each indiviudal line launch with the -log-nofilter flag. INFO | IPv4 server found: 192.168.118.180

what to do?

trying to open emulator in android studio but it is showing error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Delete any .lock files in avd folder.
it's usualy in `{user name}/.android/avd/{avd device name}/`

and if the the device is running and you can not see it, click on `Running Devices` tab. if you can not see this tab, go to `View/Tool Windows / Running Device`s

Comment: The lock file doesn't get deleted it just make new one when I open Android studio